# Best way to normalize this data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two tables, 'Product' and 'Product Packs'.

One product can appear in many product packs and a product pack can have many products (A many to many relationship).

I have also created a linking table to try and resolve this relationship but I am left with the following conundrum:

```
-------------------
|  Linking table  |
-------------------
| Prod_Id | PP_id |
|  1      |  3    |
|  1      |  4    |
|  1      |  5    |
|  1      |  6    |
|  1      |  7    |
|  2      |  5    |
|  2      |  7    |
|  2      |  8    |
|  2      |  10   |
|  2      |  4    |
```

Is this normal practice for database design? Could this be refined further?

Comment: Is the problem that two copies of product 1 appear in PP 3? Please be more specific about what the conundrum is.

Comment: yeah, i just assumed that having this kind of data repeated over and over counted as redundant data? and should be, if it could, be normalized down another level?

Comment: This is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Ah, no you can't have that. Each relationship should occur only once

Comment: @Strawberry: shouldn't the poster add a quantity column to this link table, then delete the duplicate entries? Otherwise, he won't be able to put a primary key on the two ID columns, which I think makes sense here.

Comment: @Strawberry: never mind, you just answered my question :)

Comment: the problem is the fact  ihave multiple entries of the same product_id in my linking table, this should not be the case.

Comment: @fr0s1yjack: "should not be the case" => I assume that the multiple entries in your example are intentional? If not, please fix the example.

Comment: You should probably have a compound PK on (Prod_Id,PP_id)

Comment: @Strawberry: If having repeated entries has a meaning in that table, he needs a Count column, too (but of course a PK (Prod_Id,PP_Id) ).

Comment: @Fabian they are intentional

Comment: @fr0s1yjack Then a better (3NF) design is a table (Prod_Id,PP_Id,Count) and PK (Prod_Id,PP_Id).

Comment: I'm too confused. They're there because they were added by accident, right? Because there was no PK on this table!?! Add a quantity column if you need one, but no `product` can `belong` to a `product pack` more than once.

Comment: I added an entry twice, wasn't meant to be there I have updated the table to reflect this.

Comment: In that case we could have avoided a lot of discussion :( Yes, your table is fine, just add a primary key on (Prod_Id,PP_Id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good starting point.

Taking it here you should consider, making the two fields of the table into a composite primay key.  That would prevent duplicate records as noted by @musical_coder.

You might also consider adding an integer column that indicates the quantity of products in the package.

Finally, you might want to add some metadata columns such as CreatedWhen, CreatedBy, LastUpdatedWhen, and LastUpdatedBy.  These tend to come in handy from time to time.

Comment: what would i use the count column for?

Comment: The quantity column could be used to describe the contents of the package. Package xyz contains 3 x Product1 and 4 x Product2, etc

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I would say that's no problem with this kind of relationship, but you need to be very careful when **analysing data**, but how you model is logical that a product is in a package and a  package contains  *n*  products. So that's not bad.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This is an obsolete answer since the poster fixed his example data to not contain duplicate tuples anymore**

From a database normalization perspective, this design is a bit tricky: If having two identical tuples in that table is supposed to have a meaning (e.g., a count), then this table has a multi-set semantics, which does not mix well with the relational model, since you don't have a key.

Having a table (Prod_ID, PP_Id, Count) with primary key (Prod_ID,PP_Id) is be a better (third normal form) design.

**Edit:**

So your table becomes

```
create table t (Prod_Id int, PP_Id int, Count int, primary key(Prod_Id,PP_Id));

insert into t values 
(1,3,2),
(1,4,1),
(1,5,1),
(1,6,1),
(1,7,1),
(2,5,1),
(2,7,1),
(2,8,1),
(2,10,1),
(2,4,1);

select * from t;

Prod_Id     PP_Id       Count
----------  ----------  ----------
1           3           2
1           4           1
1           5           1
1           6           1
1           7           1
2           5           1
2           7           1
2           8           1
2           10          1
2           4           1
```

Comment: but prod_ID can't be a primary key as it has to appear multiple times in the table

Comment: the key is composed of two attribute, Prod_Id and PP_Id. The meaning of that is: No two different rows in the table can be identical in both key columns at the same time. In your example data, only the pair (1,3) violates that key - I have added the transformed data above. It conforms to the create table statement.

Comment: I am still struggling to see the relevance of the count column though!

Comment: It is only relevant if you want a single pair of (Prod_Id,PP_Id) to be connected multiple times, as it has been in the initial version of your example.